# Select the optimal parameter of characteristic functions to ensure the absolute value of the roots less than $1$.

Tags: optimization, characteristic-functions

We have $n$ characteristic functions with:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:character}
u^2 - ((1+\beta)(1-\eta \lambda_i))u + \beta(1-\eta \lambda_i)= 0, 
\end{equation}
where $0 \leq m \leq \lambda_i \leq L$ ; $i\in [n]$ ;
$\beta , \eta \geq 0$.

Now we need to find the optimal parameters $\eta$ and $\beta$ to meet:
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathop{\min}_{\eta, \beta}\mathop{\max}_{i \in [n]}\{|u_i^1|, |u_i^2|\} < 1 
\end{eqnarray}
where $u_i^1$ and $u_i^2$ are the roots of the above characteristic function based on the $\lambda_i$